# Force msbuild to use a different node.exe than the one under msbuild path

Tags: c#, reactjs, windows, jenkins, msbuild

I have a .NET Framework 4.8 backend/api and a react frontend. When I try to build it locally with msbuild, it works fine.

When I build it in the jenkins pipeline i get the error "node exited with code 1". I checked the node.exe under build tools in the jenkins agent (windows) and it has the version 10... while locally i have a version above 16. So I think the version is the reason for the error.
In the jenkins agent I have also a node version 16 but not in the msbuild folder. How can I force msbuild to use another path for the node.exe?

I tried following things:

1. setting NODE_PATH (which did not affect the behaviour)
2. running the msbuild command inside the nodejs like:

```
stage('build')
{
    steps
    {
        nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'node-v20') 
        {
            bat "\"${MSBUILD}\" \"${PROJECT}"
        }
    }
}
```

3. replacing node.exe from one repository to the other and replace again after the pipeline is ready (i don't have the privileges to do so)

The only solution I can think about is to exclude the react references from the .csproj file, since i build them also separately.

It is important to notice that I don't have any rights to the jenkins agent. So i am not able to change anything on the agent side.

The preferred solution would be to tell msbuild to use the other path to node.exe

Thank you in advance for any help or hint.

Comment: Do you have some task in .csproj file related to node.exe?

Comment: Hey Vadim, no i don't have tasks

Comment: MSBuild itself doesn't use node and you indicated that your C# project doesn't use node. Where and how is your React frontend built? Do you execute `npm run build` somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to solve the problem by changing the nodejs version used by msbuild tools.
I solved the problem by using msbuild tools 2022, which has the right nodejs version in its directory